# Sphinx Readthedocs theme Font-awesome integration

Tags: django, font-awesome, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I know this may be a very silly question, but I've not managed to find **anything** online about a potential solution.

I am using [Sphinx 1.4](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.4.4/index.html) and the [sphinx_rtd_theme](https://github.com/snide/sphinx_rtd_theme) to generate some documentation for my Django project. I've been trying to find a way to use font-awesome icons in the .rst files but have found no way to do it. I've had a look at the sphinx_rtd_theme source files and the fa-* icons are included in the theme.css file. However, I'm unaware of a way actually to have them included.

Is it a directive, interpreted text or anything similar? I've tried *icon*, *fonticon* and *fa* as either of the above and none worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

I know I can potentially use raw HTML, but I'd like to avoid that if at all possible.

Comment: Have you tried looking at e.g. https://anil.io/cheatsheets/sphinx/bootstrap-restructured-text-sphinx-directives.html#font-awesome-icons? As of Jan, [apparently](http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.sphinx.devel/month=20160101), `raw:: html` was the way to go if you don't have any extra plugins.

Comment: Hi there, I had tried :fa: previously (tried it again just now, copied and pasted it from the reference you sent me) but I am getting the same error as before: `docs/source/manual/menus/mainmenu.rst:55: ERROR: Unknown interpreted text role "fa".`

EDIT: My apologies I have only now realised that it is an external library. I will have another look.

Comment: Then I guess that's only if you're using Bootstrap RST.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it looks like you're right. I'll start using the `raw` directive in that case. Thank you for the extra references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Sphinx's `rst-class` directive, as follows:

```
.. rst-class:: fa fa-fontawesome

   the font awsome flag will be attached to this paragraph
```

`rst-class` will set the class attribute for the next element as specified.

The following code renders only the icon:

```
.. rst-class:: fa fa-font-awesome

   |
```

Of course, you can also use custom classes to further style the element.

Comment: This works great, exactly what I was looking for. I'm also looking to generate a .pdf out of the same .rst files, and they don't render for the icons, but I can probably work around that. Works great for the .html files though!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use https://sphinx-panels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#inline-icons:

```
:fa:`bars`
:fa:`spinner,text-white bg-primary fa-2x,style=fa`
```

Comment: It works but for that you need to install sphinx-panels: `pip install sphinx-panels`. (https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-panels/). And add it to your conf.py: `extensions = ['sphinx_panels']`

Answer (score 0):

I am just learning Sphinx and had the same question, but using raw HTML is fine for my case. Maybe this solution will be helpful to someone out there...

In the `conf.py` file, add a link to your Fontawesome Kit Code URL

```py
html_js_files = [
    'https://kit.fontawesome.com/##########.js',
]
```

Then, use fontawesome icons in Sphinx with the raw HTML directive

```
.. |fa-fort-awesome| raw:: html

   <i class="fab fa-fort-awesome"></i>

Here is some text |fa-fort-awesome| with the icon in the middle.
```

Here is how it renders as HTML...

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In order to make the icons available on HTML and Latex download FontAwesome Web Package from  https://fontawesome.com/download, include font-awesome/svgs/solid into your project _static folder and make use of image directives like bellow:

```
The |fa-bars| function is to toggle the left Sidebar Menu between being collapsed behind the button or displayed on the screen.

.. |fa-bars| image:: _static/font-awesome/svgs/solid/bars.svg
:width: 20px
:alt: hamburguer button
```

Results:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
The <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> function is to toggle the left Sidebar Menu between being collapsed behind the button or displayed on the screen.
```